# SSH: How to get the list of servers that autocomplete when hitting tab after ssh?

Tags: ssh, bash

When I tab complete after typing ssh, I get a list of servers that I can ssh into. **How would I get that same list with a single command?**

The pseudo command would be:

`ssh --list-available-servers`

I'm unable to locate the trick in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh`

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the end of function _ssh() the block where is ssh browsing ssh config files and later

```
_known_hosts_real -a -F "$configfile" "$cur"
```

which is extracting host names from known hosts files.

You can call this command by hand, but the result is returned in variable, not written out:

```
$ . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/ssh # doesn't have to be required
$ COMPREPLY=(); _known_hosts_real -a "" && echo ${COMPREPLY[*]}
```

you will get list of suggested hosts from known hosts files (`~/.ssh/known_hosts`).

If you want also information from config file you need to add also config file argument:

```
$ COMPREPLY=(); _known_hosts_real -F ~/.ssh/config -a "" && echo ${COMPREPLY[*]}
```